# Installing kivy on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, kivy

I am trying to install ivy on Mac OS, I have come across an error which there is no documentation to fix the issue. When I try to pip install kivy the following occurs. Thanks for any help in advance

```
     xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
 error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/lp/jxxpxhsn17l_mvy8wsg953m80000gn/T/pip-build-qr4i977k/kivy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/lp/jxxpxhsn17l_mvy8wsg953m80000gn/T/pip-j52ad4nr-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/lp/jxxpxhsn17l_mvy8wsg953m80000gn/T/pip-build-qr4i977k/kivy/
```

Comment: Do you have the xcode developer tools installed? (including the command line tools)

Comment: I don't know UnholySheep

Comment: Searching for the error message I come across this solution: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254381 Please check if that fixes the problem for you